# How should I represent having transferred schools on my resume?

Tags: resume, ethics

I just graduated and am looking for my first non-internship job.

I transferred schools, and got a significantly better GPA at my newer school.

How should I represent my educational history and GPA on my CV? Putting both schools takes up a lot of real estate, and it'd be nice not to put my subpar initial GPA on display. I am thinking of just putting my latter school and GPA and listing my graduation date. Is this ethical?

Comment: Why put GPA at all? that's kind of weird. If you must, there's nothing mis-leading about "final GPA", "GPA at graduation" or other such terminology.

Comment: "it'd be nice not to put my subpar initial GPA on display" Nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is only a need to put the school you graduated from and the date of graduation. GPA is optional, but the only relevant GPA is that at the time of graduation. I think that adding the other school and the GPA at that school would just be too much noise on the CV. The only exception perhaps being applying for a position at the first school.

Comment: Agreed.  Any additional information is just confusing....